# Refresh bearer token and remove old token

Tags: jwt, bearer-token, refresh-token

I'm using `Bearer tokens` to authorize user requests. The following scheme is used:

When a user authenticates the application, he gets a token with `30 minutes expiration`. With an interval of 30 minutes the client sends `refresh-token` request (getting new token), and `remove-old-token` request (to delete old token). It takes about **0.1 seconds** to update the key.

The problem is, if any other request is sent during this 0.1 seconds, it will be categorized as unauthorized and the user will be automatically logged out.

There is a solution to not delete the old token (which expires in 10 minutes), however, if a user signed in with the 'Remember me' function, he gets a token with much more expiration time, and it should be deleted when new token is obtained.

There is also a solution to send `remove-old-token` after 1 minute from `refresh-token`. But this seems like a workaround.

Is there a way to perform refresh token in a better way?

Comment: You shouldn't have to delete the old key if it was expired, and just obtain a new token a minute before it expires. And I hope you're doing this with OAuth2 instead of inventing your own.

Comment: @Evert You're right. But we have to remove old token, because for 'Remember me' functionality there is a token with much longer expiration time, we can't leave it undeleted..

Comment: @Evert I use JWT authorization

Comment: JWT and OAuth2 are not mutually exclusive. OAuth2 has an excellent solution and recommendations for this with separate refresh and access tokens